# Text not adjusting on a single line

Tags: html, css, xhtml, dreamweaver

The problem that i am facing is that text inside the a tag is not adjusting on a single line.

Here's my html.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style5.css" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="outer">

        <ul>
            <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">content</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">search</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">more</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="homepage">

            <a href="#">Set as Homepage</a>

        </div>

        <div id="clear">
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="pic">
            <img src="logo.png">
            <div id="content">
                <p> Secure Search </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="forms">

            <form>
                <input type="text" name="submit" size="70" style="font-size:20pt;"/>
            </form>
            <div id="pic_2">
                <img src="powerd-by-google.png">
            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            © 2012 - <a href="#">We Respect your Privacy</a> - <a href="#">About AVG Secure Search</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>


</html>
```

and here's my css.

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: white;
}

h1,h2,h3
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

p,ul,ol,li
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#outer
{
    background-color: rgb(67,68,71);
}

#outer ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border-left: 1px solid;
}

#outer li
{
    float: left;

}

.current
{
    background-color: rgb(56,63,137);
}

#outer a
{
    width: 90px;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border-right: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
}

#outer a:hover
{
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}

#outer .current a:hover
{
    color: white;
    background-color: inherit;
}

#homepage a
{
    float: right;
    font-weight: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(67,68,71);
    display: inline;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    border-right: none;
}

#homepage a:hover
{
    color: white;
    background-color: inherit;
}

#clear
{
    clear: both;
}


#wrapper 
{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

#pic
{
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 389px;
    position: relative;
}

#content
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 90px;
}

#forms
{
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

#pic_2
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 867px;
}

#footer
{
    width: 500px;
    margin: 375px auto 0px;
}

#footer a
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

now the problem is with the `a` tag in the homepage div, i have tried very hard but i have no idea why its text is not adjusting on a single line instead it seems to creep up on multiple lines.

Any suggestions in this matter would be really helpful.

thank you.

Comment: Did you try not setting the width of <a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about the 'set as homepage' button.

If so, The issue is that your css is writing a fixed with to the element inherited from `#outer a` which is making that element `90px` wide.

You can fix this by simply adding the css style  `width: inherit;` to `#homepage a`

Example:

- **http://jsfiddle.net/2jByx/1/**

Comment: wow...man i am amazed i didn't noticed it. Awesome man really thanks for the help.

Comment: haha no worries man, we all miss things from time to time ^_-

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `width` to the "set as homepage" element

```
#homepage a {
 .....
  width: 120px; //added width
}
```

Take a look at here, http://jsfiddle.net/VkmHr/

is that you looking for?

Comment: Still takes two lines, isn't it?